# FactoryImpl to set atts via props for bound inputs

Tags: dynamic, properties, constructor, polymer

First, thanks for any advice. I am new to all of this and apologize for any obvious blunders.

Second, the question:

In an interface for entering clients that often possess a number of roles, it seemed efficient to create a set of inputs which possessed both visual characteristics and associated data binding based simply on the inputs name.

For example, inquirerfirstname would be any caller or emailer who contacted our company.

The name would dictate a label, placeholder, and the location in firebase where the data would be stored.

The single name could be used--I thought--with a relational table (state machine or series of nested ifs) to define the properties of the input and change its outward appearance and inner bindings through property manipulation.

I created a set of nested iffs, and console logged the property changes in the inputs, but their representation in the host element (a collection of inputs that generated messages to clients as well as messages to sales staff) remained unaffected.

I attempted using the ready callback. I forced the state change with a button.

I was unable to use the var name  = new MyInput( name).  I believe using this method would be most effective but am unsure how to "stamp" the JavaScript into a heavyweight stamped parent element.

An example of a more complicated and dynamic use of a constructor and a factory implementation that can read database (J-son) objects and respond to generate HTML elements would be awesome.

In vanilla a for each would seem to do the trick but definitions and structure as well as binding would not be organic--read it might be easier just to HTML stamp the inputs in polymer by hand.

I would be really greatful for any help. I have looked for a week and failed to find one example that took data binding, physical appearance, attribute swapping, property binding and object reading into account.

I guess it's a lot, but each piece independently (save the use of the constructor) I think I get.

Thanks again.

Jason

Ps: I am aware that the stamping of the element seems to preclude dynamic property attribute and binding assignments. I was hoping a compute attribute mixed with a factoryimpl would be an option (With a nice example).

Comment: Some example code would be helpful. Show us what you have already tried.

Comment: I ended up sidelining the project for a moment, but have a closely related question based on the same set of elements, and related issues. I have sibling elements.  One element has inputs, the second element a notecard   that will fill in text as the user enters data on a caller. I wanted to reveal text that would make the user entered text appear as the user typed. The text would fill in the space between the entries to make the text readable. I used a session variable as a counter on blur, and as the user stepped through the inputs, bound properties on the one sibling were set by the on blur

Comment: The change of properties via inputs shows fine on the view. The change of properties via function and the counter shows fine via the console log, with a jsonstringify(this.$.id.prop.subprop).toString(), even in the target sibling, prop.subprop reads in console... on screen... in the binding... zero.  I notified but to no avail.